# ItemType when datasource is datareader

Tags: asp.net

I want to set the ItemType in my repeater, but my datasource is a datareader, not a class.

How can I do thats?

Help me please.. Thank

Comment: But `ItemType` is a getter, not a setter (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeateritem.itemtype(v=vs.110).aspx) how do you expect to set its value?

Comment: My question is if it's possibile to set the ItemType even if the DataSource is DataReader..

Comment: Your question (at least how I understand it) doesn't make sense because your can't set the `ItemType` regardless. The `ItemType` property depends on the type of data you are binding and that can only be determined at run time. If you bind a `DataReader` your item type will like be an anonymous class created at run time or a DataRow collection. You can't set its value programmatically.

Comment: I don't want to set its value programmatically, I want to set it in my aspx page, but I don't know how should I do it, because the datasorce is datareader, not a class..

Answer (score 0):

If the DataSource is a `DataReader`, your ItemType needs to be either a [DbDataRecord](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdatarecord.aspx) (which implements [IDataRecord](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatarecord.aspx)) or better, `IDataRecord` directly.

Example (assuming you are getting an `Id` column back):

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt" ItemType="System.Data.IDataRecord" runat="server" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Item.GetInt32(Item.GetOrdinal("Id")) %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

But I think the above is probably worse than simply doing `Eval` or `Cast`. I can see the benefit when you are binding to a custom business object but not when you are using a `DataReader`.